# How do I deal with "Ambiguous reference to member '=='" in RxBluetoothKit?

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, bluetooth, rx-swift, rxbluetooth

Trying to scan for `Bluetooth` `peripherals` using `RxBluetoothKit` I get an `error` called

> "Ambiguous reference to member '=='
>   using this code:

```
func observeState() -> Observable<[BluetoothState]> {
    return manager.observeState()
           .startWith(manager.state)
           .do(onNext: { print("CHECK POWER", $0) })
           .filter{ $0 == .poweredOn }
           .take(1)
           .do(onNext:{
               print("POWERED ON", $0)
           })
           .flatMap { _ in
               self.manager
                   .scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
                   .map { BlePeripheral(peripheral: $0.peripheral) }
                   .do(onNext: {
                       print($0.peripheral.name)
                       print($0.peripheral.identifier)
                       print($0.peripheral.connected)
                    })
           }
    }
```

The error is on `.filter{ $0 == .poweredOn }`

If I remove everything from `flatMap` and onwards, the error disappear but obviously I need to have that part at some point. Not sure I understand the `error`. I have looked at question/answers on the same error but I'm still not sure how it applies to my case or what the `compiler` wants me to do. Appreciate any pointers to how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a type mismatch. The return type of function is Observable<**[BluetoothState]**>, but inside flatMap return type is Observable<**BlePeripheral**>

Comment: Ah, nice! Good catch. So what's the solution? Divide it up into different parts in methods? Or how do I deal with this?